# Can i get bool in VM switched from ContentPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I try to set a bool in a content page so i can perform a function in my ViewModel. I am trying to set the bool in the content page on a button press. And then I need the view model to know that its set to true. The reason i am doing this because i need to swap functions of button

I need to swap these two just in case my question makes no sense maybe this will make it clearer

```
<Label
    x:Name="makeLargerEN" 
    FontFamily="{StaticResource IconsFontFamily}"
    HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
    Text="{Binding MakeLargerEN}"
    TextColor="{DynamicResource AccentColor}"
    VerticalTextAlignment="End">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding MakeWebViewLargeCommand }" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <Label.FontSize>
        <OnIdiom
            x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
            Phone="25"
            Tablet="30" />
    </Label.FontSize>
</Label>
<Label
    x:Name="makeLargerEN" 
    FontFamily="{StaticResource IconsFontFamily}"
    HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
    Text="{Binding MakeLargerEN}"
    TextColor="{DynamicResource AccentColor}"
    VerticalTextAlignment="End">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding MakeWebViewLargeCommandEN }" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <Label.FontSize>
        <OnIdiom
            x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
            Phone="25"
            Tablet="30" />
    </Label.FontSize>
</Label>


public async void MakeWebViewLarge()
{
    if (IsCz)
    {
        var popup = new WordAndPhrasePopup(htmlSourceExplanation.Html);

        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(popup);
    }

    else
    {
        var popup = new WordAndPhrasePopup(htmlSourceExplanation.Html);}
    }



<ToolbarItem 
        x:Name="btnChangePositions"
        Priority="0" Clicked="ChangePosition"
        Text="{Binding ChangePositionsButton}" />

ContentPage / this is where i am trying  to set the bool 
    public Dictionary()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new DictionaryViewModel();
        btnChangePositions.Text = "CZ/EN";
        viewModel = new DictionaryViewModel();
        viewModel.IsCz = true;
    }

    public bool isSwap = false;
    private void ChangePosition(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        isSwap = !isSwap;

        czView.RemoveBinding(ExtendedWebView.SourceProperty);
        enView.RemoveBinding(ExtendedWebView.SourceProperty);


        if (isSwap)
        {
            viewModel.IsCz = false; 
            btnChangePositions.Text = "EN/CZ";
            czView.SetBinding(ExtendedWebView.SourceProperty,("EN"));
            enView.SetBinding(ExtendedWebView.SourceProperty,("CZ"));

        }
        else
        {
            viewModel.IsCz = true;
            btnChangePositions.Text = "CZ/EN";
            czView.SetBinding(ExtendedWebView.SourceProperty, ("CZ"));
            enView.SetBinding(ExtendedWebView.SourceProperty, ("EN"));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please segment your code into pieces for view (xaml), code behind (xaml.cs) and your view model. Your code is very hard to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating two different instances of your VM - your XAML is using `BindingContext`, and your code-behind is using `viewModel`

```
InitializeComponent();
BindingContext = new DictionaryViewModel();
btnChangePositions.Text = "CZ/EN";
viewModel = new DictionaryViewModel();
viewModel.IsCz = true;
```

instead create a single instance with two different references

```
InitializeComponent();

BindingContext = viewModel = new DictionaryViewModel();

btnChangePositions.Text = "CZ/EN";

viewModel.IsCz = true;
```